# How can I create a junction using cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, ntfs, junction

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043603/does-cygwin-understand-ntfs-junction-points) shows that cygwin’s soft links are somewhat different from ntfs junctions. I’d like cygwin to create a real junction. I thought about running `mklink` but, hell, there is no `mklink.exe`. [Apparently](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/e4ffae45-b71c-493c-b0d2-cfeb0045f5c8/), it’s part of the shell command. There I’m stuck.

Any idea how I can do that on a script ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer, running `cmd.exe /c mklink /j name target` did the job. I leave the answer here in case someone runs into the same trouble.

**EDIT**: Added `/j` switch as pointed out by Ken Williams in the comments.

Comment: If you want an actual junction, then you probably should use the `/j` flag: `cmd /c mklink /j name target`.  Otherwise according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx I think you end up with a Windows-style file symbolic link.

Comment: The recent windows native symlinks have advantages over the more limited junction points, which aren't treated correctly by some software (e.g., anything running on the java jvm, for example).  See   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648819/how-to-make-symbolic-link-with-cygwin-in-windows-7

Comment: Depending on your exact requirments, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648819/how-to-make-a-symbolic-link-with-cygwin-in-windows-7#18660841) could be a alternative solution worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Seems `ln` (from `coreutils`) and `winln` (from `cygutils-extra`) are unable to create a junction; they only creates hard or symlinks.

The only solution is to use `cmd`:

```
cmd.exe /c mklink /j $TARGET $SOURCE
```

or PowerShell:

```
powershell.exe New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path "Link" -Target "Target"
```

- [How is the a junction link creation command on MSYS2 terminal](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1315)